# Change the background color of a UIBarButtonItem in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UINavigationBar with a right UIBarButtonItem.

How do I change just the background color of the button (not the text)?

```
UIBarButtonItem *postButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"POST" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(postButtonPressed:)];

// Changes text color
postButton.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

How do I make the background color change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `appearance` proxy for this,

Create a 1x1 pixel image with the color you prefer. In this case this image's name is "icons_gb.png". Then add following code to  your `AppDelegate.m` . Image color will be repeated in the button's background.

```
UIImage *btnBg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icons_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:btnBg 
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I just put it in my one view that I want changed and it worked.

Comment: You can use `UIEdgeInsetsZero` instead of `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Using storyboard or XIB, You could add UIButton directly to a navigation bar and change UIButton background color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think its the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it by:

```
yourNavigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

The color of navigation bar also be changed.

If you want to change only UIBarButtonItem, use my custom class:

UIBarButtonItem+Custom.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBarButtonItem (Custom)
+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barItemWithImage:(UIImage *)img size:(CGSize)size target:(id)target action:(SEL)selector;
@end
```

UIBarButtonItem+Custom.m

```
#import "UIBarButtonItem+Custom.h"

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (Custom)
+ (UIBarButtonItem *) barItemWithImage:(UIImage *)img size:(CGSize)size target:(id)target action:(SEL)selector
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);

    [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *forward = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];

    return forward;
}
@end
```

Comment: This is the bar. I want just the right button color to change, not the whole bar.